# Proportional font breaks company overlays

Tags: company-mode, variable-pitch

When I use a proportional font with buffer-face-mode, it breaks company's overlay, because company obviously counts offset from the left margin, as well as pads suggestions on the right in character positions, expecting it to be same width always. Is there a way to use a variable width characters, but still get the proper rectangular box for company? If there's an alternative solution like replacing company with other similar mode I would like to know it too.

[image]

Comment: Yes, there is: improve the code to use ad-hoc frames for popups.  We welcome help to do that.

Comment: Hi, @Stefan, is it really possible using overlays? I quickly glanced over ov.el, and it seems to me, it's not.

Comment: @Alaks Not using overlays, no.

Comment: @Dmitry, thanks! So what is that code which needs improvement then? Emacs's own?

Comment: @Alaks Yes. For context, Stefan who commented above is a core Emacs developer and a former Emacs maintainer of many years.